# vlookup and edit one worksheet from another

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I'm looking to vlookup and update cost/balance in inventory table/sheet from purchase record using VBA.

```
Worksheets("Purchase Record")(VLOOKUP(H16,Inventory[#Data],10,0)= _
   Worksheets("Purchase Record").Range("O16") 'lookup and add stock 

Worksheets("Purchase Record")(VLOOKUP(H16,Inventory[#Data],7,0)= _
   Worksheets("Purchase Record").Range("C16"+ (VLOOKUP(H16Inventory[#Data],7,0).VALUE
```

Comment: You can't just add a VLOOKUP formula in its worksheet state to VBA. Can you explain what exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: @Pancho - maybe add a screenshot of your setup? It will help visualize what you want to do. We can guess from the code you have, but more detail would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like what you're trying to do:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim tbl As ListObject, sht As Worksheet, m, id, rw As Range

    Set sht = Worksheets("Purchase Record")
    Set tbl = sht.ListObjects("Inventory")

    id = sht.Range("H16").Value 'value to match against the table

    m = Application.Match(id, tbl.ListColumns("Data").DataBodyRange, 0) 'try to match the ID

    If Not IsError(m) Then

        Set rw = tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows(m) '<< this is the matching row in your table/listobject

        'best guess at what you're wanting to do...
        rw.Cells(10).Value = sht.Range("O16").Value
        rw.Cells(7).Value = rw.Cells(7).Value + sht.Range("C16").Value

    End If

End Sub
```